# g++ issue for passing arguments

Tags: c++, g++, pass-by-reference

Please consider these partial codes:

```
//Tree.h
class Tree {

private:
    Limits joint_limits;

public:

    Tree();
    Tree(Configuration root, const Limits& _joint_limits);
    ~Tree();
//the rest of the class
```

second header file:

```
//RRT.h
class RRT {
private:
    Tree roadmap;

public:
    ~RRT();
    RRT();
    RRT(Configuration _init_conf, Limits _joint_limits);
//the rest of the class
```

In the `RRT` constructor, I have this line of code:

```
RRT::RRT(Configuration _init_conf, Limits _joint_limits) {
    roadmap(init_conf, _joint_limits);
}
```

When I try to compile it, I have the following error:

```
no match for call to ‘(Tree) (Configuration&, Limits&)’
```

Why `g++` thinks I'm sending a reference in the RRT constructor and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are trying to call a function called `roadmap` or its `operator ()`.

Probably it's a mistake.
You can do this:

```
RRT::RRT(Configuration _init_conf, Limits _joint_limits) {
    roadmap = Tree(init_conf, _joint_limits);
}
```

or

```
RRT::RRT(Configuration _init_conf, Limits _joint_limits)
    : roadmap(init_conf, _joint_limits) {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling `roadmap` as if it were a function or declared `operator()`. To initialise it, you must use the syntax for member initialiser list:

```
RRT::RRT(Configuration _init_conf, Limits _joint_limits)
    : roadmap(init_conf, _joint_limits);
{
}
```